# What does Tobi mean by "There lies truth in a single consciousness that has abandoned all individuality"?

Tags: naruto

In Chapter 594, Tobi says, "There lies truth in a single consciousness that has abandoned all individuality."

What is the context of this statement? Is there something specific he is referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think he is referring to the Eye of The Moon Plan to unite the world under Infinite Tsukuyomi, thus being able to control every living creature, and to cease conflicts by removing any free will.

So looks like that with this line he is just supporting/justifying his idea again.